# WPF ObservableCollection not updating?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

Can't seem to get an ObservableCollection to update. The TreeView shows empty.
Error: this type of collectionview does not support changes to its sourcecollection from a thread differentfrom the dispatcher thread.

Class level var

```
public ObservableCollection<TSItem> tsItems { get; set; }
```

Initialize Components

```
tsItems = new ObservableCollection<TSItem>();
bwRun.DoWork += bwRun_DoWork;
InitializeComponent();
tvTest.ItemsSource = tsItems;
```

from the background worker I use the following method to add to the collection

```
 private void AddTreeViewItem(TSItem item)
 {
     tsItems.Add(item);
 }
```

xaml

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="249" Margin="140,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Do you actually start your background worker? I wasn't able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: yes, updated post. The worker is started in the Loaded event.

Comment: tsItems  should be public...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dispatch changes to UI thread:

```
 private void AddTreeViewItem(TSItem item)
 {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tsItems.Add(item)));
 }
```

Comment: Switched TSItem to public class along with making the collection public and still doesn't update

Comment: With this I'm getting Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

Comment: I beleive this error is somehow related to your image source creation. If you dynamically create a bitmap image, you should freeze it by calling Freeze() method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms557735(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok I got this to work, I needed to call Freeze() on the ImageSource in TSItem

Answer (score 3):

You *have* to invoke back onto the UI thread before updating your observable collection.

As a shortcut to *just get it working*, consider `Application.Dispatcher.Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.This requires a reference to `PresentationCore` so may not be great for MVVM if you want to be *super pure* about it.

---

If you want to be purer one way or another, you need to do a bit more work. Most of this involves trapping the `SynchronizationContext` of the UI thread.

- Create your own implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged that wraps a `SynchronizationContext` and forwards the events of an internal `ObservableCollection`
- Grab the `SynchronizationContext` in your constructor using `SynchronizationContext.Current`. This only works if your constructor is accessed on the UI thread.
- Pass a `SynchronizationContext` into every class that needs ones.

Answer (score 1):

@Somedust is correct.  I would also add that you say that you are updating the observable collection via the background worker.  If you are doing that, you need to ensure that you are back on the UI thread when doing so.

Comment: Is there a way to update it without being on the UI thread? I need the user to see it's progress in the TreeView as it's working? Is this going to require me creating a worker for each task then updating it on complete?